# How to write the Javascript that gives each link a custom URL to jump to on click according to it's child element's text contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if it is possible to write a Javascript that gives each link a custom format URL to go to on click.

```
<!-- example set one -->
<a href="javascript:myfunction()" class="relative-url" target="_blank">
  <span id="input01">campfire<span>
  <span id="input02">red<span>
</a>
<!-- example set two -->
<a href="javascript:myfunction()" class="relative-url" target="_blank">
  <span id="input01">pepe<span>
  <span id="input02">green<span>
</a>
```

How to write the custom javascript to formulate an URL for each `<a class="relative-url">`  ?

```
<script>
 // use text content of child element id=input01 and id=input02 to 
 // formulate an URL for it's parent div or <a>
 // eg. https://www.example.com?type=campfire&color=red
 // eg. https://www.example.com?type=pepe&color=green
</script>
```

Any good idea?  Thanks a lot~

Comment: Could you show us your javascript code? attribute id must be unique in the document, so you should change your html because it is invalid. You can use class or change id value.

Comment: Hi, the js code is not there yet, no clear idea about what approach should be taken yet.  Is there a way to target making use of the content of the child element only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it at runtime, you could do something like this. I used jQuery since you tagged it in your question.

```js
 $('.relative-url').each(function() {
      let type = $(this).find('.input01').text();
      let color = $(this).find('.input02').text();
      this.href = `https://www.example.com?type=${type}&color=${color}`
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- example set one -->
<a class="relative-url" target="_blank">
  <span class="input01">campfire</span>
  <span class="input02">red</span>
</a>
<br/>
<!-- example set two -->
<a class="relative-url" target="_blank">
  <span class="input01">pepe</span>
  <span class="input02">green</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I see! That's a clean and helpful solution to use `$(this).find()`! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer I thought I'd offer a non-jQuery approach in case that might be of help; explanatory comments are in the code:

```js
// caching a refernce to the document, and some helper functions as I don't
// enjoy repetitive typing all that much:
const D = document,
  get = (sel, ctx = D) => ctx.querySelector(sel),
  getAll = (sel, ctx = D) => [...ctx.querySelectorAll(sel)],
  // a simple function to update an element with new properties ('props'):
  update = (elem, props) => Object.assign(elem, props),
  // a named function that takes an element (though it realistically
  // should be a HTMLAnchorElement):
  createURL = (elem) => {
    // here we use destructuring to declare the variables of type and color
    // to the text-content of each of the <span> elements found within the
    // current element, after we trim the leading/trailing white-space:
    let [type, color] = getAll('span', elem).map((el) => el.textContent.trim());
    // calling the update() function, passing in the current element
    // and an object of properties to update with the new property-value:
    update(elem, {
      href: `${elem.href}?type=${type}&color=${color}`
    });
  };

// retrieves all <a> elements in the document, and iterates over that Array
// of nodes and calling the createURL() function on each of them:
getAll('a').forEach(createURL);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  color: #363;
  margin: 1em auto;
  inline-size: fit-content;
}

a::after {
  content: '(URL: "' attr(href) '")';
}
```

```html
<!-- example set one -->
<a href="#" class="relative-url" target="_blank">
  <span>campfire</span>
  <span>red</span>
</a>
<!-- example set two -->
<a href="#" class="relative-url" target="_blank">
  <span>pepe</span>
  <span>green</span>
</a>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3rkug6mv/1).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).